# Create A Facebook Status Update Box for Website

Tags: facebook

I want to know how I can update my Facebook status (and allow other users to update theirs) from a website.
I found this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/status.set/ but couldn't figure out how to get the information from a form to the URL.

Form: USERS STATUS

https://api.facebook.com/method/status.set?status=USERS+STATUS&access_token=**************************************&format=json

Could anyone shed some light on this, or help me? :(

**Update!**
I found this piece of coding

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Great Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
      </script>
      <script>
         FB.init({ 
            appId:'128083010546416', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
         });

         FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
            message: 'Facebook for Websites is super-cool'});
      </script>
     </body>
 </html>
```

So, how do I get the text from a form (or something) to the "message" box?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't **fill** the box in the Facebook Dialogs with the data you have. Instead you should use [`FB.api`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.api/):

```
var body = 'Reading Connect JS documentation'; // Content to share
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occurred');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```